# Ionic - Create tag when user presses go/enter on keyboard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I currently have a mobile app whereby you can search for certain items, the way the search functionality currently works is when you press **Space** this will then be created into a tag. Instead of when the user press' spacebar, I want it to create the tag when the user press' **go/search/enter** on the mobile keyboard.

The below code is the function i currently use and creates the tag when " " is present. This needs to change as some items are 2 words such as **Chai Seeds**

```
  constructor(public keyboard: Keyboard, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public apiAuthentication: ApiAuthentication, private http: Http) {
    this.tags = [];
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      tags: ['']
    });
    this.myForm.get('tags')
      .valueChanges
      .subscribe((value: string) => {
        if(value.indexOf(' ') > -1) {
          let newTag = value.split(' ')[0];
          console.log(newTag);
          if(newTag) {
            this.tags.push(newTag);
            this.myForm.get('tags').setValue('');
          }
          this.searchRecipeDB(this.tags);
        }
      });
    }
```

I can't work out how the go/enter button works on mobile devices so if you could show me what to change it would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're using ion-input,ion-textarea, you can listen to the keypress events:

```
<ion-input (keypress)="onPress($event.which) ... >
```

.ts:

```
onPress(keyCode: number): void {
 if(keyCode === 13) { 
   // the keyCode for return/go/enter is 13 (iphone's)
   doWhateverYouWant();
 }
}
```

you can search for other keyCodes here:
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_basic_latin.asp